# Replace regex same-pattern occurrences with different replacements

Tags: php, regex

To avoid SQL injections, like all of us do, I sanitize all the user-provided strings. Now I want to give to the users the possibility to save formatted text and the way I thought to do it has been copying the Stack/WhatsApp method:

- `*word*` -> **bold**
- `_word_` -> *italic*

Before uploading the text to the DB, I check for this character and, if there's a match, I replace

- `*word*` -> `<b>word</b>`
- `_word_` -> `<i>word</i>`

The problem is that I'm sure there's a way, using a **regular expression**, to say: if you match this standard (i.e. `*word*`) replace:

- the **first** occurence `*` with the open tag `<b>`
- the **second** occurence `*` with the close tag `</b>`

The code works, the not-working part is the one in the second `foreach ()` loop, inside the `if ()`. My last desperate attempt after many has been this, but it actually has no meaning even for a non-regex-expert like me. I tried to divide the regex into its three different parts, recalling them in `preg_replace` with `$1` and `$3`.

```
    function textFormatting($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', $text); //transform any 2+ space in 1 space
    $text = nl2br($text);
    //$text = preg_replace('/[\n]+/', '<br>', $text);
    $text = explode(' ', $text);
    $regexAY =
        [
            '/([*]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([*]{1})/' =>
                [
                    "pattern" => "*",
                    "openTag" => "<b>",
                    "closeTag" => "</b>"
                ],
            '/([_]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([_]{1})/' =>
                [
                    "pattern" => "_",
                    "openTag" => "<i>",
                    "closeTag" => "</i>"
                ]
        ];

    $newText = [];
    foreach ($text as $key => $word) {
        foreach ($regexAY as $regex => $value) {
            if (preg_match($regex, $word)) {
                //$word = preg_replace($regexAY[$regex]["pattern"], $regexAY[$regex]["replacement"], $word);
                $word = preg_replace('/$1/', $regexAY[$regex]["openTag"], $word);
                $word = preg_replace('/$3/', $regexAY[$regex]["closeTag"], $word);
            }
        }
        if ($word !== '') { array_push($newText, $word); }
    }

    return implode(' ', $newText);
    }

    $text = "     Hi _this_ _text_ _is a test_
       *for*        
       text     _formatting_     
       so       don't pay   *attention*
      d";
    echo $text;
    echo "\n -------- \n";
    $text = textFormatting($text);
    echo $text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `preg_replace` method with `\*(.*?)\*` as the pattern:

```
$text = "This is a *word* and here are *more*. That is the case *with this too*.";

$output = preg_replace("/\*(.*?)\*/", "<b>$1</b>", $text);
echo $output;
```

Returns:

```
This is a <b>word</b> and here are <b>more</b>. That is the case <b>with this too</b>.
```

Look here if you want to play with the regex or add more examples.
https://regex101.com/r/aH6xr8/2

Comment: Here's the answer! This is exactly what I meant. To deep understand it, could you tell me in words what `(.*?)` means? Cause for my (really modest) knowledge of regexes this would mean `.*`: equal to [^\n], `?`: 0 or 1, and in this way I didn't really understood what `(.*?)` does. Thanks Spencer!

Comment: You're welcome! Anything inside `()` is a capture group. `.` is any character, `*` quantifies any character as any number of times, `?` makes it not "greedy" (makes the capture group as small as possible.)

Comment: Nearly everything I know about regex I learned at https://regexone.com It makes it super simple to learn regex basics and I worked through the exercises in only a few days.

Comment: `\*([^*]*)\*` accomplishes the same thing as `\*(.*?)\*` but is greedy, which makes it faster. Probably doesn't matter much in this case, but if you start processing larger bold blocks, you'll see a pretty big improvement. This regex also matches newlines inside bold blocks, which might be useful. For italics, use `_([^_]*)_`